# Convert nanoseconds since 01/01/2000 to timestamp in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'm currently querying a database with a timestamp column expressed in nanoseconds since 2000/01/01. For example, I have the value:

```
600393600000000000
```

Which can be converted to a date using the following code (written in Dart but just as an example):

```
  DateTime epoch = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1);
  var date = epoch.add(new Duration(microseconds:(600393600000000000 / 1000).floor()));
  print(date);
```

This would print:

```
2019-01-10 00:00:00.000
```

My goal is to convert this into a postgresql timestampz through a query rather than using any application code. I know postgresql has the to_timestamp() function which can be used to create a timestamp from unix time but can't find a method for this.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Divide by 1000000000, add the number of seconds between the epoch and 2000-01-01, and call `to_timestamp` on the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as already mentioned, use the following construct:

```sql
to_timestamp(extract(epoch from '2000-01-01 00:00:00Z'::timestamptz) + (<your_nanos>::decimal / 1000000000))
```

...e.g.:

```sql
select to_timestamp(extract(epoch from '2000-01-01 00:00:00Z'::timestamptz) + (600393600123456789::decimal / 1000000000));
```

...yields:

```
         to_timestamp          
-------------------------------
 2019-01-10 00:00:00.123457+00
(1 row)
```